# Finding all neighbours of a node sliding tile

Tags: java, array, sliding-tile-puzzle

So I have some code which finds neighbours of a given State. So the positions the blank tile (which is represented as 0 in my code) can be moved.

I am doing the 3x3 tile puzzle. The goal state is represented like this :

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 0
```

Say I have a problem state which is:

```
8 5 1 
3 4 7 
0 6 2
```

I would call the `findNeighbours()` method on this State and it should return two states like this .

```
8 5 1                             8 5 1 
3 4 7   (This is a right move)    0 4 7  (This is an up move)     
6 0 2                             3 6 2
```

The reason I'm posting here is because I'm not getting the performance I'd hoped for and I'm assuming this `findNeighbours()` is the issue as the code is clunky to say the least! I should also point out that state is an array which looks something like `state = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,0}` and `neighbours` is an `ArrayList` which I am adding every State to

```
   public void findNeighbours() {
        for (int i = 0; i < state.length; i++) {
            if (state[i] == 0) {
                if (i % 3 != 0) {
                    int[] left = new int[9];
                    System.arraycopy(state, 0, left, 0, left.length);
                    int temp = left[i];
                    left[i] = left[i - 1];
                    left[i - 1] = temp;
                    State newState = new State(left,this, "left");
                    this.neighbours.add(newState);

                }
                if (i % 3 != 2) {
                    int[] right = new int[9];
                    System.arraycopy(state, 0, right, 0, right.length);
                    int temp = right[i];
                    right[i] = right[i + 1];
                    right[i + 1] = temp;
                    State newState = new State(right, this, "right");
                    this.neighbours.add(newState);
                }
                if (i > 3) {
                    int[] up = new int[9];
                    System.arraycopy(state, 0, up, 0, up.length);

                    int temp = up[i];
                    up[i] = up[i - 3];
                    up[i - 3] = temp;
                    State newState = new State(up, this, "up");
                    this.neighbours.add(newState);
                }
                if (i < 6) {
                    int[] down = new int[9];
                    System.arraycopy(state, 0, down, 0, down.length);
                    int temp = down[i];
                    down[i] = down[i + 3];
                    down[i + 3] = temp;
                    State newState = new State(down,  this, "down");
                    this.neighbours.add(newState);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is really hard to read. I suggest the following:

1. Have four methods `slideUp`, `slideDown`, `slideLeft`, `slideRight`, each copying the `this` and applying the slide operation.
2. In the neighbour generation routine just check all the four, and whichever of them return a non-null result add to the list; finally, return the list.
3. Cache the index of the zero tile.

I had this in mind:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SlidingTilePuzzleNode {

    private int[] state = new int[9];

    private int zeroTileIndex;

    public SlidingTilePuzzleNode() {
        for (int i = 0; i < state.length - 1; ++i) {
            state[i] = i + 1;
        }

        zeroTileIndex = state.length - 1;
    }

    private SlidingTilePuzzleNode(int[] state, int zeroTileIndex) {
        this.state = state.clone();
        this.zeroTileIndex = zeroTileIndex;
    }

    public SlidingTilePuzzleNode slideUp() {
        int x = getX(zeroTileIndex);
        int y = getY(zeroTileIndex);

        if (y == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        int nextx = x;
        int nexty = y - 1;
        int nextIndex = xyToIndex(nextx, nexty);
        SlidingTilePuzzleNode node = new SlidingTilePuzzleNode(state,   
                                                               nextIndex);
        int tmp = node.state[nextIndex];
        node.state[nextIndex] = node.state[zeroTileIndex];
        node.state[zeroTileIndex] = tmp;
        return node;
    }

    public SlidingTilePuzzleNode slideDown() {
        int x = getX(zeroTileIndex);
        int y = getY(zeroTileIndex);

        if (y == 2) {
            return null;
        }

        int nextx = x;
        int nexty = y + 1;
        int nextIndex = xyToIndex(nextx, nexty);
        SlidingTilePuzzleNode node = new SlidingTilePuzzleNode(state,   
                                                               nextIndex);
        int tmp = node.state[nextIndex];
        node.state[nextIndex] = node.state[zeroTileIndex];
        node.state[zeroTileIndex] = tmp;
        return node;
    }

    public SlidingTilePuzzleNode slideLeft() {
        int x = getX(zeroTileIndex);
        int y = getY(zeroTileIndex);

        if (x == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        int nextx = x - 1;
        int nexty = y;
        int nextIndex = xyToIndex(nextx, nexty);
        SlidingTilePuzzleNode node = new SlidingTilePuzzleNode(state,   
                                                               nextIndex);
        int tmp = node.state[nextIndex];
        node.state[nextIndex] = node.state[zeroTileIndex];
        node.state[zeroTileIndex] = tmp;
        return node;
    }

    public SlidingTilePuzzleNode slideRight() {
        int x = getX(zeroTileIndex);
        int y = getY(zeroTileIndex);

        if (x == 2) {
            return null;
        }

        int nextx = x + 1;
        int nexty = y;
        int nextIndex = xyToIndex(nextx, nexty);
        SlidingTilePuzzleNode node = new SlidingTilePuzzleNode(state, 
                                                               nextIndex);
        int tmp = node.state[nextIndex];
        node.state[nextIndex] = node.state[zeroTileIndex];
        node.state[zeroTileIndex] = tmp;
        return node;
    }

    public Collection<SlidingTilePuzzleNode> getNeighbors() {
        List<SlidingTilePuzzleNode> neighborList = new ArrayList<>(4);
        SlidingTilePuzzleNode node = slideUp();

        if (node != null) {
            neighborList.add(node);
        }

        node = slideDown();

        if (node != null) {
            neighborList.add(node);
        }

        node = slideLeft();

        if (node != null) {
            neighborList.add(node);
        }

        node = slideRight();

        if (node != null) {
            neighborList.add(node);
        }

        return neighborList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int index = 0;

        for (int y = 0; y < 3; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; ++x) {
                sb.append(state[index++]);
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static int getX(int index) {
        return index % 3;
    }

    private static int getY(int index) {
        return index / 3;
    }

    private static int xyToIndex(int x, int y) {
        return y * 3 + x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SlidingTilePuzzleNode node = new SlidingTilePuzzleNode();
        SlidingTilePuzzleNode tmpNode;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            System.out.println(node);

            String cmd = scanner.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();

            switch (cmd) {
                case "quit":
                case "exit":
                    System.exit(0);

                case "up":
                    tmpNode = node.slideUp();

                    if (tmpNode != null) {
                        node = tmpNode;
                    }

                    break;

                case "down":
                    tmpNode = node.slideDown();

                    if (tmpNode != null) {
                        node = tmpNode;
                    }

                    break;

                case "left":
                    tmpNode = node.slideLeft();

                    if (tmpNode != null) {
                        node = tmpNode;
                    }

                    break;

                case "right":
                    tmpNode = node.slideRight();

                    if (tmpNode != null) {
                        node = tmpNode;
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.